# Integrate test Selenium with VSTS

Tags: selenium-webdriver, azure-pipelines

I made a set of tests of IU with Selenium, creating for it a Class Library, when integrating it with VSTS, what should I do so that the tests run when I build it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If it is the .net test project, you can refer to this article: [Get started with Selenium testing in a CI pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/test/continuous-test-selenium)

Simple steps:

1. Create a Unit Test project
2. Add Selenium.WebDriver, Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver, Selenium.WebDriver.IEDriver, Selenium.Firefox.WebDriver, Selenium.WebDriver.PhantomJS.Xplatform packages to your project
3. Coding

Sample:

```
namespace Partsunlimited.UITests
{
  using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
  using OpenQA.Selenium;
  using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
  using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
  using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;
  using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
  using OpenQA.Selenium.PhantomJS;
  using System;

  [TestClass]
  public class ChucksClass1
  {
    private string baseURL = "http://your-website.azurewebsites.net/";
    private RemoteWebDriver driver;
    private string browser;
    public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }

    [TestMethod]
    [TestCategory("Selenium")]
    [Priority(1)]
    [Owner("FireFox")]

    public void TireSearch_Any()
    {
      driver = new FirefoxDriver();
      driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
      driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
      driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(this.baseURL);
      driver.FindElementById("search - box").Clear();
      driver.FindElementById("search - box").SendKeys("tire");
      //do other Selenium things here!
    }

    [TestCleanup()]
    public void MyTestCleanup()
    {
      driver.Quit();
    }

    [TestInitialize()]
    public void MyTestInitialize()
    {
    }
  }
}
```

4. Create new build definition
5. Add NuGet task to restore packages
6. Add Visual Studio Build task to build projects
7. Add Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment task to deploy test agent
8. Add Windows Machine File Copy to copy files to agent machine
9. Add Run Functional Tests task to run test

You also can use Visual Studio Test task to run test (Replace step 6 ~9), a blog: [Running Selenium Tests as part of your release with VSTS Release Management](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dgartner/2016/02/23/running-selenium-tests-as-part-of-your-release-with-vsts-release-management/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the blogs you suggest are good. Let's do it!!

Comment: The tasks suggested in this article were recently deprecated. I would not recommend following this documentation until that is corrected. https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/pull/6156